# Split data from a column and insert to another table in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to split data from Username column in a table like this:

```
Table1
ID  Username
1   UserA,UserB,UserC
```

and I want to insert it to another table. the result will be like this:

```
Table2
ID  Username
1   UserA
1   UserB
1   UserC
```

is this possible to do this in postgresql?

thanks in advance

Comment: Would there always be 3 usernames in each record?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen no, it can be dynamic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can split the value and then unnest it:

```
insert into table2 (id, username)
select t1.id, ut.username
from table1 t1
  cross join unnest(string_to_array(t1.username), ',')) as ut(username)
```